# Remove last value added to a text area using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am adding letters and words to an empty text area using the following code:

HTML:

```
<textarea id="Content"></textarea>

<button class="AddTo" value="a">a</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.AddTo').on('click', function() {
  $('#Content').append($(this).val());
});
```

How can I delete the last value added to the text area such as "a" or "apple" without clearing everything? Basically I want a delete button to remove the last character.

Comment: provide html code too?

Comment: by last word you mean preceeded by space or other character?

Comment: please clear up some more your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should keep an array of the values added to the textarea in javascript. If you want to revert back 1 word (or more) you would simple pop off the values from the array then populate the textarea from the shortened array.

Example:

```
var values = [];

$(function(){

    $('.AddTo').on('click', function() {
        values.push($(this).val());
      $('#Content').val( values.join(" ") );
    });

    $('.Backspace').on('click', function(){
        values.pop();
        $('#Content').val( values.join(" ") );
    });

});
```

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/stLzjmsa/)**

*Demo with freeform text field: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/stLzjmsa/4/)*

Comment: that's an awesome way of doing it !!

Comment: This is great JRulle, but what if I want a screen reader to read back the text? How can it populate the actual textarea?

Comment: @Anthony_Z   -   I don't understand, the script is populating the `textarea` and shouldn't present an issue for a screen reader. The `values` array is more like a history for the data in the `textarea`

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep track of the values inserted, you can use an array to do that as given below, then use that to remove the content

```js
var values = [];
$('.AddTo').on('click', function() {
  values.push($(this).val());
  $('#Content').val($('#Content').val() + values[values.length - 1]);
});
$('.remove').click(function() {
  if (values.length) {
    $('#Content').val(function(i, v) {
      return v.slice(0, -values.pop().length)
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="Content"></textarea>
<br />
<button class="remove">Remove</button>
<input type="button" class="AddTo" value="a" />
<input type="button" class="AddTo" value="apple" />
<input type="button" class="AddTo" value="some" />
<input type="button" class="AddTo" value="value" />
```

Answer (score 1):

how about the following?

```js
var str = "here goes some text";
var lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf(" ");
str = str.substring(0, lastIndex);
$("div").text(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick

```
var string = "a for apple";

string = string.substring(0, string.lastIndexOf(" "));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you could add your values like this:

```js
$('.AddTo').on('click', function() {
  $('#Content').append('<p> Some value </p>');
});

$('.Remove').on('click', function(){
  $('#Content p:last').remove();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="AddTo" value="Test">Add</button>
<button class="Remove">Remove</button>

<p id="Content"></p>
```

**Explanation:**

`#` referees for the id selector.

`$('#Contents p)` finds the p tag in the element with id Contents.

`$('#Contents p:last')` selects last p tag in the element with id Contents.

`.remove()` function removes it from the page.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to create a backspace button that removes the last character from the text:

```
$('#Backspace').click(function() {
  $('#Content').text(function (_,txt) {
    return txt.slice(0, -1);
  });
});
```